# How to change Google account after signed in

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, googlesigninaccount, google-one-tap

I use [javascript API](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference) because i want fully customized button, themes from Google not enough for my needs. I wrote small example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gi001-6t0x6q?file=/src/App.js). Problem is after sucessfull signed in, i cant choose another account. I try change [configuration](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#IdConfiguration), but without result.

Answer (score 0):

I read more about this, and found answer there [Google identity docs: How it works](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview#how_it_works):

> - **One Tap and Automatic sign-in** are triggered only when users have
>   signed in to Google before loading your web pages.
> - **With the Sign In With Google button** flow, users are prompted to
>   sign-in to Google when the button is pressed, establishing an active Google session

My conclusion: in order for the user to choose another account that does not have a current session in the browser, you need to use Google button instead of On tap. You can create a button using [google.accounts.id.renderButton](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.renderButton). Setting up Google button can only be done within the framework of the API described [in section GsiButtonConfiguration](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#GsiButtonConfiguration), because render creates a button inside an iframe and there is no access to it.

[i changed my sandbox for demonstrate this](https://codesandbox.io/s/gi001-6t0x6q?file=/src/App.js)